# What resources do an unused pthread mutex or condition variable allocate?

Tags: linux, macos, pthreads, mutex, condition-variable

Suppose that I have a mutex/condition variable. I initialize (pthread_mutex_init/pthread_cond_init), but never use them (no lock operations, no signal/wait).

Do these unused objects allocate other resources other than the memory they occupy?

(I'm interested in linux and OSX behavior in this regard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although POSIX explicitly contemplates that these functions may fail due to a lack of resources (the `EAGAIN` and `ENOMEM` error codes), neither the Linux glibc nor OSX implementations of `pthread_mutex_init()` or `pthread_cond_init()` allocate any resources.  You can see this by direct inspection of the source code:

The Linux glibc implementation of `pthread_mutex_init()` is in [`nptl/pthread_mutex_init.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_mutex_init.c;t=glibc-2.26) (see the function `__pthread_mutex_init()`).

The Linux glibc implementation of `pthread_cond_init()` is in [`nptl/pthread_cond_init.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_cond_init.c;t=glibc-2.26) (see the function `__pthread_cond_init()`).

The OSX implementation of `pthread_mutex_init()` is in [`libpthread/pthread_mutex.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libpthread/libpthread-218.1.3/src/pthread_mutex.c.auto.html) (see the functions `pthread_mutex_init()` and `_pthread_mutex_init()`) and [`libpthread/internal.h`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libpthread/libpthread-218.1.3/src/internal.h.auto.html) (see the macro `_PTHREAD_LOCK_INIT`).

The OSX implementation of `pthread_cond_init()` is in [`libpthread/pthread_cond.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/libpthread/libpthread-218.1.3/src/pthread_cond.c.auto.html) (see the functions `pthread_cond_init()` and `_pthread_cond_init()`).

Comment: Thanks! I've checked these myself, and indeed it seems that these don't allocate any resources.